# KnockoutJS Fields added to array updating previous rows

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

KO 'observable' is not releasing after I add a new row.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: newName" />
<button data-bind="click: add">Create</button>
```

**JS**

```
self.newName = ko.observable("");

self.add = function () {
    self.clients.push({
          Name : self.newName,
    })
}
```

**LIST-Start**

```
<ul>
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Joe</li>
<ul>
```

**LIST PRODUCED**
I use the fields and add 'Foo' which works

```
 <ul>
        <li>John</li>
        <li>Joe</li>
        <li>Foo</li>
    <ul>
```

Then I add another name 'Bar'
.. and now I have (2) 'Bar', 'Foo' is replaced

```
<ul>
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Joe</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
<ul>
```

Then I add another name 'JarJar', and now I have (3) 'JarJar', 'Bar' is replaced

```
<ul>
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Joe</li>
    <li>JarJar</li>
    <li>JarJar</li>
    <li>JarJar</li>
<ul>
```

However, when I delete each row, it does delete the select row, not all 3

How do I stop the observable 'on the fields' when add rows?

I still need the newly added row added to the KO Array so I can access it at a later time.

I think I am missing something after the self.add to either release the observable for the field, or create a = new something so the newName is a separate Array object. (not sure at all .. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the missing `()` you are passing in the `Name` the `ko.observable` function itself and not the value what it holds.

That is why you have the duplication becuase all the created objects in the `clients` array shares the reference to the same function.

Here is the fixed code what should work correctly:

```
self.newName = ko.observable("");

self.add = function () {
    self.clients.push({
          Name : self.newName(),
    })
}
```

Comment: the row are now correct. However, when I call another function on the newly added row, I get : 
** Property 'Name' of object #<Object> is not a function **

Comment: If you need `Name` as observable you need to write: `self.clients.push({
          Name : ko.observable(self.newName()),
    })`

Comment: I just noticed: After I add a new row using the button. I clear the fields (using simple jquery). When the fields are empty, I click the button (with not values) and KO adds the same data from the previous row as a new array item. Can we tell KO to forget/clear its 'memory' after we have added a new array item?

Comment: If you clear the fields with jQuery knockout can't track that the field changed. So it will store the previous values in the observables like `newName`. To solve this don't use jQuery to clear the fields but set the observable to empty: `self.add = function () {
    self.clients.push({
          Name : ko.observable(self.newName())
    })
    self.newName("");
}` Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/UXbFT/